# KQL Query for creating domain list from UserPrincipalName

Tags: kql, azure-sentinel

is there a way for building a list of unique user domains in a delimited format from sentinel signin logs? Signin logs has user principal name and can be extended to split the domain name as below.

```
extend UserDomains = split(UserPrincipalName,'@')[1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [make_set()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/makeset-aggfunction) aggregation function, for example:

```
T
| extend UserDomains = split(UserPrincipalName,'@')[1] 
| summarize UserDomains = make_set(UserDomains)
```